# Highlighting JavaScript Function results? I have created a function to highlight the specific area to highlight, but it does not highlight?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a function intended to highlight a specific elements of a function result. It is part of simple interest calculator I am building, i have created a separate function to add a class to the specific element, then I have called that function in the result which should display on the browser but it does not seem to highlight it.

I have copied a snippet of the JS, CSS and HTML:

```js
function highlight_p() {
  var element = document.getElementById("principal");
  element.classList.add("highlight");
}

function compute() {
  // Ensure all values are _numbers_
  p = Number(document.getElementById("principal").value);
  r = Number(document.getElementById("myRange").value);
  n = Number(document.getElementById("years").value);

  const newDate = new Date();
  newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + n);
  let result = "If you deposit " + highlight_(p) + ", " + "<br>";
  result += "at an interest rate of " + r + "%," + "<br>";
  result += "you will receive an amount of " + getFutureValue(p, r, n).toFixed(2) + "," + "<br>";
  result += "in the year " + (newDate.getFullYear());
  showResult(result);

}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button>
<p id="result" onsubmit="hightlight_p()"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: I made you a stacksnippet. Please update to make it a [mcve]

Comment: It's worthwhile doing a couple of things: put your code through a validator to make sure you don't have the sort of errors that @mplunjan has spotted and make sure you do have the element you want to change correctly passed to the highlighting function. And look for errors in your browser dev tools - or on the Stack snippet system.

Answer (score 0):

- IDs need to be unique
- Ps do not have onsubmit events
- You do not have `showResult` or `getFutureValue` anywhere
- You do not have anything with `id="principal"`
- `highlight_(p)` is not valid JS

Perhaps you mean this?

```js
const highlight = str => `<span class="highlight">${str}</span>`;
const currency = num => new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(num);

const getFutureValue = (principal,rate,year) => {
    var interest = rate/100+1;
    return currency(principal*Math.pow(interest,year))
}

document.getElementById("compute").addEventListener("click",function() {
  // Ensure all values are _numbers_
  p = +document.getElementById("principal").value;
  r = +document.getElementById("rate").value;
  n = +document.getElementById("years").value;

  const newDate = new Date();
  newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + n);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `If you deposit ${highlight(currency(p))} at an interest rate of ${highlight(r+"%")},<br>
  you will receive an amount of ${highlight(getFutureValue(p, r, n))} in the year ${highlight(newDate.getFullYear())}`;
  
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#rate, #years { width:50px }
```

```html
$<input type="number" id="principal" /> at <input type="number" id="rate" />% for <input type="number" id="years" /> years

<button id="compute">Compute Interest</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: I tweaked it some more